# Rewrite URL to match Locationmatch

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I would need some assistance with a rewrite.

There's two rules which needs to be applied:
1. Base the RewriteCond on HTTP_USER_AGENT
2. Add paths to the URL to match with LocationMatch

What I've right now which is broken:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^git
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /git/$1 [L]
```

Removing the RewriteRule and querying the path right away works fine, but running with this rule renders apache "unable to find file".

The match is a LocationMatch  `<LocationMatch "/git/">`, so I'm not sure if a RewriteRule can point at that?

Full config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/subgit/repos

    <Directory /home/subgit/repos>
        Options       None
        AllowOverride none
        Order         allow,deny
        Allow         from all
    </Directory>

CustomLog /home/subgit/logs/access_log combined
SuexecUserGroup subgit subgit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^git
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /git/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]

ScriptAlias /git/ /home/subgit/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/

 <LocationMatch "/git/">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from env=AUTHREQUIRED
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "subgit"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /home/subgit/etc/subgit
    Require valid-user
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The solution was to use [PT] rather than [L].